# Postgres: incorrect sorting if timestamp in smtp format

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I am working on a project where we send some data using SMTP and I have some weird issues with sorting timestamps if they are already stored in an smtp format like `'Dy, FMDD Mon YY HH24:MI:SS TZ'` (for example `'Fri, 18 Aug 17 14:15:26 UTC'`).

An isolated case, sorting using smtp_message_time:

```
psql=> select
             time,
             to_char(time, 'Dy, FMDD Mon YY HH24:MI:SS TZ') as smtp_time
         from
             messages
         order by
             smtp_time;

            time            |          smtp_time
----------------------------+-----------------------------
 2017-08-18 14:15:26.537+00 | Fri, 18 Aug 17 14:15:26 UTC
 2017-08-18 14:17:33.57+00  | Fri, 18 Aug 17 14:17:33 UTC
 2017-07-10 14:11:46.035+00 | Mon, 10 Jul 17 14:11:46 UTC
 2017-07-10 14:21:27.032+00 | Mon, 10 Jul 17 14:21:27 UTC
 2017-07-10 14:21:40.541+00 | Mon, 10 Jul 17 14:21:40 UTC
 2017-07-10 14:23:01.928+00 | Mon, 10 Jul 17 14:23:01 UTC
 2017-07-10 14:23:15.508+00 | Mon, 10 Jul 17 14:23:15 UTC
 2017-07-10 14:24:14.322+00 | Mon, 10 Jul 17 14:24:14 UTC
 2017-07-10 14:26:21.426+00 | Mon, 10 Jul 17 14:26:21 UTC
 2017-07-10 14:35:38.044+00 | Mon, 10 Jul 17 14:35:38 UTC
 ....
 2017-08-16 16:03:29.214+00 | Wed, 16 Aug 17 16:03:29 UTC
 2017-08-16 16:04:16.037+00 | Wed, 16 Aug 17 16:04:16 UTC
 2017-08-16 16:05:07.444+00 | Wed, 16 Aug 17 16:05:07 UTC
 2017-07-26 13:49:13.217+00 | Wed, 26 Jul 17 13:49:13 UTC
(96 rows)
```

I found the issue after spotting negative intervals in some final results.

1. Is there any logical explanation for that behaviour?
2. Is there anything I am missing or I can do to have the format parsed correctly?

If possible, I would rather operate on the smtp format as my first choice rather than on the Postgres one as it is already stored that way and some code reworking would need to be done.

On a side note, I had already noticed I needed to use `interval(timestamp with time zone, timestamp with time zone)` to have the timezone taken into account, I also noticed that I could put different days of a week and results stayed the same.

Comment: you're ordering by a text column, so postgresql is ordering by alphabetical order. you could order by the `time` column

Comment: @HaleemurAli The time column exists only in the example, the real data has only the smtp one. But you're right, of course it's the text and in the alphabetical order. Now it's seems obvious but it's been a long day ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL is surprisingly flexible in the input it accepts for timestamps.

```
SELECT 'Fri, 18 Aug 17 14:15:26 UTC'::timestamptz;

      timestamptz       
------------------------
 2017-08-18 16:15:26+02
(1 row)
```

So you could just

```
ORDER BY smtp_time::timestamptz
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing into the right direction, I didn't realise it was actually blindly interpreted as text. Funnily, I will need to do something like `SELECT to_char(min(smtp_time::timestamptz), 'Dy, FMDD Mon YY HH24:MI:SS TZ')` as I put the output into `oldest_message_time` bash variable.

Comment: I wonder if you know if smtp_time column is actually interpreted as text, I would expect it to be sorted alphabetically in that case.

Comment: That depends on its data type. You never said what it was, but since your output was sorted alphabetically, I assumed it must have been a string data type.

Comment: You're correct, it was a text and it was sorted alphabetically. I shouldn't have asked questions late-late night.